# How to accept the 'Did you mean?' terminal/git suggestion

Tags: linux, git

This is a simple question.

Sometimes on a Terminal when you make a small mistake the console asks ¿Did you mean ...? - ¿Is there a way to quicky accept the suggestion?.

For example:

```
$ git add . -all
error: did you mean `--all` (with two dashes ?)
```

Is there a command that repeats the last line, but with the two dashes?

If you forget to write `sudo`, you can just do `sudo !!` and it will solve your problem. I want to know if there is something similar but for the `error: did you mean` case.

Comment: Don't think so. The suggestion is made by `git` and not `bash`. The behavior you ask about would need to be implemented by `git` as well.

Comment: Change `foo` into `bar` in last command by executing `^foo^bar`, or make a global change using `!!:gs/foo/bar/` Read more in bash-manual about [Event Designators](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Event-Designators)

Comment: @LevLevitsky yep sry, just changed the question to git. Anyway, the question is the same.

Comment: @alejoss, ...unfortunately, even with that change, my answer remains accurate -- the command is entered at the shell, the error comes from git, and the shell can't see what errors git emitted to automate changing the command buffer in accordance with any suggestion included in that output.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy true. I just don't understand the downvote, it seemed a vald question to me. I'm not a pro.

Comment: Yeah, no idea there. I'd understand someone voting to move it to superuser, but the downvote isn't obvious to me either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of...

```
$ git add . -all
error: did you mean `--all` (with two dashes ?)
```

...the message is written by git **directly to the terminal**. This means that bash has no way of knowing what message was written; it would be literally impossible to implement anything in the shell that could automate putting that correction in place without making programs run under the shell considerably less efficient (by routing their output through the shell rather than directly to the terminal) and changing their behavior (if they ever call `isatty()` on their stdout or stderr).

---

That said, you can certainly run

```
^-all^--all
```

...if you haven't turned history expansion off, as with `set +H` (if off, it can be reenabled with `set -H`). I typically *do* turn this functionality off, myself; it's often more trouble than it's worth (making commands which would work perfectly well in scripts break in interactive shells when they use characters that history expansion is sensitive to, particularly `!`).